# Angular2- Virtual Scrollbar with dropdown NGbDropDown or simple Select Dropdown

Tags: angular, github, scroll

I am using Angular 5 application. I am using ngbDropDown as dropdowns at some places. I want to implement angular2-virtual-scrollbar on this dropdown.

Is there way it works with simple select dropdown or ngbDropdown. This is how code looks.

```
<virtual-scroll [items]="items" (update)="scrollItems = $event" (end)="fetchMoreRecords($event)">
              <div class="dropdown-menu" ngbDropdownMenu>
                <h5 class="dropdown-header">Heading</h5>
                <div class="dropdown-item" *ngFor="let item of scrollItems">
                    item.itemValue
                </div>
              </div>
            </virtual-scroll>
```

or with simple Select dropdown

```
<virtual-scroll [items]="items" (update)="scrollItems = $event" (end)="fetchMoreRecords($event)">
          <select id="selectId" [formControlName]="virtualDropdown" class="custom-select"
            required>
            <option *ngFor="let item of scrollItems" [ngValue]="item.itemValue">
              item.itemValue
            </option>
          </select>
        </virtual-scroll>
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check whether this npm package helps https://github.com/farin99/angular2-virtual-select

Comment: I don't want to install a new library in application as i am already using virtual scroll in other areas as well for tables mainly.

Comment: I don't want to install a new library in application as i am already using virtual scroll in other areas as well for tables mainly.